# How to install Defense4All for OpenDaylight?

Tags: openflow, sdn, opendaylight, defense4all

(This is a duplicate question from ServerFault, but seems that is not a right place to ask and it got downvoted for no reason, so I re-post here)

Basically I am setting up an OpenDaylight controller for my SDN. And I am trying to install an application - Defense4All, which from the documentation, will communicate with the controller host.

I am reading the installation guide of it in https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Defense4All:Installation_Guide , but it seems that the link of getting binary of Defense4All is dead, and I can't find a way to get the binary of Defense4All. I managed to compile from source but I have no idea how to proceed after successful build. Anyone idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue. Hope someone feels useful.

I managed to compile the source with `mvn install`, which it successfully did all the compilation but it did not give me a binary. But I am able to do so using `mvn package`.

To be specific, under directory `dfapp` after unzipping the source zip file:

```
vm:~/defense4all-release-helium-sr3/dfapp$ mvn package
```

After a long build, you will find the binary file in `dfapp.aggregate/target`

Make sure you allocate enough memory (say, 2048) to the VM or it will suffer from insufficient memory error.

There are also some dependencies such as `git` and `rpm`, it varies with your machines, so take notice of the error log.